# the order of an element of power k in a group G

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

if *g* is an element of a group G and *g* has finite order, let's say *n*. then prove that the order of *g^k* is equal to (*n/gcd(n,k)*)
i.e |*g^k*|= *n/gcd(n,k)*

my attempt:
if *n* divides *k* then *g^k=e*. then the order of *g^k* is 1 and 1 = *n/gcd(n,k) = n/n*
if *n* doesn't divide *k* then *k= nr+s, where s<n and r,s are integers*
then *g^k= g^nr g^s = g^s* then I do not know what to do
I am stuck here

Comment: lcm should be gcd

Comment: edited  now I will think again thank you

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)